# Open or inflate the Actionbar menu on longclick only - Android

Tags: java, android, drop-down-menu, android-actionbar, inflate

I'm trying to make the actionbar menu (onCreateOptionsMenu) open ONLY on a long-click. How would I achieve this? At the moment I have it working for just a single short press/click using the following code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    // TODO: Only onlongclick should the menu be revealed
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_menu_id, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_home:
            open_home();
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_how_to:
            open_how_to();
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_rate:
            open_rate();
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_about:
            open_about();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I'd like the menu to ONLY open for a long click (sort of like a hidden/trick feature). I've looked into onLongClickListener but can't get it to work. Thanks for your help! Really appreciate it.

Comment: Are you trying to show the menu only when you perform a long click into something or do you want to perform the action (like open_how_to() ) only when a menu item is long clicked:

Comment: I want to show the menu only when the menu button is longclicked. After that everything will function as per normal...just single short clicks will do for the menu items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring this one out myself. There's 2 ways of doing it. Either a context menu or a alert dialog menu. The alert dialog menu allow icons whereas the context menu does not.

See my answer here: 
[Open Actionbar Menu on Longclick - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20702715/open-actionbar-menu-on-longclick-android/)